# Differences between WCF self-hosting and IIS-hosting

Tags: .net, wcf

Is WCF Service that hosted in the IIS should be written thread safe?
Which differences should be taken in consideration in the development phase between those two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MSDN Article, [Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) probably has all the information you need.

As for development phase, you can use the built-in hosting from Visual Studio, and then deploy it to IIS for stage testing afterwards. You can use Visual Studio's feature to run two projects at start-up: your application project and the WCF project.